# I can't load tomcat in browser using my domain ip address

Tags: tomcat

I can load tomcat using localhost but if I used my server ip address it's give me timeout error. Can someone help me? Below I attached screen shots. I'm first time using tomcat.

**Localhost:**
[image: Localhost working fine]

**Server:**
[image: server url not working]

Comment: Welcome to SO! The connection on external IP is possibly blocked by your firewall?

Comment: @Selaron i pause firewall and check but same issue

Comment: Are requests other than localhost routed through proxy (which eventually does not permit ports other than 80 and 443)? Btw. you are downvoted likely becaus you question is not programming related and would have better asked at serverfault.com

Comment: your tomcat hosted in aws. if so then enable the port in inbound

Comment: @AshokKumarN done but same error

Comment: chekc whether the service is running or not

Comment: @AshokKumarN server is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your tomcat is bind with localhost. Can you follow the below steps to bind the tomcat to specific IP address.

1.Edit `tomcat/conf/server.xml`.

2.Specify a bind address for that connector.

```
<Connector 
    port="8080" 
    protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
    address="173.82.151.75"
    connectionTimeout="20000" 
    redirectPort="8443" 
  />
```

3. Restart the Tomcat server

Comment: can you check `netstat -an | grep '8080'` or `netstat -an | find "8080"` in the console window?

Comment: TCP 0.0.0.0:8080 0.0.0.0:0 Listining

Comment: TCP [::]:8080 [::]:0 Listining,  these are the outputs i get

Comment: Can you add host entry in the `hosts` file which is on the location `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` ? like this `<<IP address>>     <<yourHostName>>`

Comment: 173.82.151.75 server.revport.net like this? still not wrking

Comment: Command netstat shows the your tomcat is listening on 0.0.0.0. It shows that tomcat is binded with all the ip on this machine. Are you trying `localhost:8080`  and `173.82.151.75:8088` on the same machine ?

Comment: Check your windows-firewall feature in control panel. Outbound and inbound port should allow port 8080.